# Breakpoint in App.XAML.CS not working

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

Whenever I put a breakpoint in the WPF App.XAML.cs file, the breakpoints are not hitting. As if the file is not executed at all. So weird.... There is no the usual 'yellow breakpoint' indicating the breakpoint is not hit. It just runs the program as if the file is not being executed at all

Anybody know why?

here's my App.Xaml.cs code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using Abt.Controls.SciChart;
using Abt.Controls.SciChart.Model.DataSeries;
using Abt.Controls.SciChart.Utility;
using Abt.Controls.SciChart.Visuals;
using Abt.Controls.SciChart.Visuals.Axes;
using Abt.Controls.SciChart.Visuals.Annotations;
using Abt.Controls.SciChart.Visuals.RenderableSeries;
using Abt.Controls.SciChart.ChartModifiers;
using Abt.Controls.SciChart.Numerics.CoordinateCalculators;

namespace Hub
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            CUtilities.WCFCalls = new List<string>();
        }
    }
}
```

here's my app.g.cs file

```
#pragma checksum "..\..\App.xaml" "{406ea660-64cf-4c82-b6f0-42d48172a799}" "788CF6544127ABDC6D6160DE3D084FC8"
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.18444
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Automation;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Media.Effects;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;
using System.Windows.Media.TextFormatting;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Shell;


namespace Client {


    /// <summary>
    /// App
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : System.Windows.Application {

        private bool _contentLoaded;

        /// <summary>
        /// InitializeComponent
        /// </summary>
        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("PresentationBuildTasks", "4.0.0.0")]
        public void InitializeComponent() {
            if (_contentLoaded) {
                return;
            }
            _contentLoaded = true;

            #line 4 "..\..\App.xaml"
            this.StartupUri = new System.Uri("MainWindow.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);

            #line default
            #line hidden
            System.Uri resourceLocater = new System.Uri("/Client;component/app.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);

            #line 1 "..\..\App.xaml"
            System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, resourceLocater);

            #line default
            #line hidden
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Application Entry Point.
        /// </summary>
        [System.STAThreadAttribute()]
        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("PresentationBuildTasks", "4.0.0.0")]
        public static void Main() {
            Client.App app = new Client.App();
            app.InitializeComponent();
            app.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I seem to remember this happening with older versions of Visual Studio, it's like it would take a second or two for the debugger to hook in to the process or something. I found I could force it manually with `Debugger.Break();` In any case try manually deleting the bin/obj folders and doing a rebuild, sometimes it's also the result of the incremental compilation getting itself confused.